# How to batch insert mysql LOAD DATA?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a list of absolute filenames (csv files). I want to batch insert them using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

Problem: I'm not able to collect the sql statements in batches before executing them as batch:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ? INTO TABLE mytable");

for (String filename : filenames) {
    ps.setString(1, filename);
    ps.addBatch();
}

ps.executeBatch();
ps.commit();
```

Result:

> Error during commit of 1 files: Parameter index out of range (1 >
>   number of parameters, which is 0)

The sql wildcard parameter is not recognized. But how can I then get the absolute filename it the statement, if not with a `?` wildcard?

Comment: `LOAD DATA` is not valid for a prepared statement. It's not found in the "SQL Syntax Allowed in Prepared Statements" list, documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think prepared statements support `LOAD DATA` as you have in mind.  As far as I know, only literal values in queries may be represented by parameters.  But you may use ordinary string concatenation here:

```
String sql1 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '";
String sql2 = "' INTO TABLE mytable";

Statement s = con.createStatement();    // use a regular statement
for (String filename : filenames) {
    String query = sql1 + filename + sql2
    s.addBatch(query);
}

s.executeBatch();
s.commit();
```